# Android onDraw() is a suspicous method call

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, android-view

For an Android canvas game I use the following (minimized) method to request a redraw of the SurfaceView:

```
    private void refreshView() {
        c = surfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        synchronized (surfaceView.getHolder()) {
            surfaceView.onDraw(c);
        }
```

But since the last android sdk (22.2.1) it gives me a Lint warning on *surfaceView.onDraw*

> Suspicious method call; should probably call "draw" rather than
>   "onDraw"

When I use draw instead of onDraw, the screen stays black. When I use postInvalidate(), the rendering performance reduces.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html - `draw()` is the documented method of rendering a canvas to the view.

Comment: @Simon I know, but draw() doesn't call onDraw() in some way.

Answer (score 3):

By convention, methods from Android API named like `On***` should not be called directly by your code, but only by Android OS itself. I hope, someone will tell you what to use instead of it in this situation...
For the performance: if performance can become a problem, why don't you use OpenGL? (or a library that uses OpenGL)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The reason I'm using canvas instead of OpenGL is that this is actually for a game engine, and because of external factors, the rendering needs to be as easy as possible.

Comment: It's not intended for professional use, but to let people with almost no programming experience see how you can show simple objects on the screen and manipulate (override) it in their own way if they want to. OpenGL is just overkill for that.

Comment: @Bas then why use Android for that? It is not suitable for people without experience in programming, there are much easier things. For example, the most dead-easy and yet powerful thing for drawing is Cairo.

Comment: Sorry, i'm saying it wrong. It's more for people who already have some knowledge about java (like rendering) and want to experiment with Android. We just give them some basis where they can build further from. Why not introduce them to OpenGL? Because openGL's is way harder to understand than canvas, and especially if you don't have much experience. If they want to, they can use openGL later.

Answer (score 3):

I know is not the best solution, but I used `@SuppressLint("WrongCall")` to avoid the error message.

Comment: With Gradle:
android {
...

    lintOptions {
        disable 'WrongCall'
     }
}

(We have some code which should do the "wrong" calls.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of onDraw(c) use **draw(c)** and change Method onDraw(Canvas canvas) to **draw(Canvas canvas)** .hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error. After I change the onDraw function to another name, ie. Fix_onDraw, all thing is ok.